# How to delete an extra " in GEOjson (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, api, openlayers, geojson

I tried to manipulate an object GEOjson to display it in my map OpenLayers. But my GEOjson is invalid. 
First, in my API I request to my database to recover the geometry, then I parse it thanks to GEOjson.parse :  `GeoJSON.parse(data, {GeoJSON : 'geometry'});`
the data looks like this :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[0.699526704561417,49.5855766259652],[0.699132813373672,49.5855472259388],[0.698829663954256,49.5852457878428],[0.698308423811369,49.5855523688003],[0.699127661396565,49.5862481964213],[0.699752271011022,49.5859030239836],[0.699526704561417,49.5855766259652]]]]}",
                "properties": {
                    "libgeo": "Bois-Himont",
                    "nature": "Parcelle bâtie"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[0.696220319484454,49.581274516207],[0.696272071456392,49.5820438187077],[0.697147417334422,49.5815673912038],[0.697102005023975,49.5814546891317],[0.697047441685103,49.5812624281067],[0.6969844037675,49.5812621313821],[0.696220319484454,49.581274516207]]]]}",
                "properties": {
                    "libgeo": "Bois-Himont",
                    "nature": "Parcelle bâtie"
                }
            }, etc...
```

Then in my script.js (that files had the aim to display the map and the GEOjson) I parse the data thanks to JSON.parse, but  the line geometry is invalid because there is an [extra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8gf4.png) " and the type and the coordinates is surrounded by ".

How can I delete the extra " and delete the " for the type and the coordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry is a string when it should be an object.  After the first parse you will need loop through the features and parse each geometry string into an object.

```
var myGeoJSON = JSON.parse(myText);
myGeoJSON.features.forEach( function(feature) { feature.geometry = JSON.parse(feature.geometry) });
```